# Find the interval for application of Rolles theorem.

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

$x^3+x^2+m=5\ln{|x|}$, depending on any real $m$.

I did the first steps and did the derivative, got the solutions from the derivative, $x=1$; $f(1)=2+m$ and got some solutions but the answer says that there should be $x=0$ and $x=1$. How did they find that $x=0$?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you are looking for ? For the solutions of the equation $x^3+x^2+m=5ln{x}$ ? $x=1$ is a solution $ \iff m=-2 \quad$. $x=0$ is not a solution, since $ \ln$ is not defined in $0$.

Comment: ok, so the answer must be wrong

Comment: isnt there supposed to be an interval for rolle to be used?

Comment: @TheIntegrator yeah,there is, you are supposed to deduce it

Comment: $x\in [0,1]$ is not a solution as $0$ is not a  solution. Are you sure the equation is correct??

Comment: @TheIntegrator i forgot the absolute value of x